# Immutable-JS: Merge a List of Maps by key

Tags: reactjs, flux, immutable.js, redux

I have an app-state object, which sort of looks like this:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
    $isLoading: true,
    currentPage: 0,
    totalPages: 1,
    results: []
});
```

When I fetch from server (using `fetch` API), I want to set `$isLoading` to false, and merge `currentPage` and `totalPages` in from the response. That's easy enough so far using `merge`. I'm not quite sure how to elegantly merge in the `results` node. They're `Immutable.Map`s, and should merge based on the `_id` property. Is there an elegant way to work it into this bit of code?

```
return state.merge({
    $isLoading: false,
    currentPage: res.page,
    totalPages: res.pages,
    results: 'something' // Take old results, merge with res.results
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to change your merge function to mergeDeep:

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeDeep